# How to set the tables in the CENTER of the window

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

Please,can anyone help me for this problem:

I have built the code in the way that each time I press one of the radio buttons on of the 5 tables I have must be visible in the window while the other 4 are invisible.
The only problem I have is to make the content of this table which has 2 colomns,,,Emer and Nota in the center of the second panel,,,because I have separated the window in 3 panels,

The first panel contains the radio buttons which are ok:)
The second panel contains the 5 tables,,,1 for each radioButton,,,I only need that when I press one of the buttons the selected table to show on the CENTER of the second panel.
The third panel contains only one button,but it's fine;)

Plz help me.
If you need the code tell me to write it here and I would like to put a print screen on it,so you can understand better...I hope so.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few ways to solves this.  The simplest being just remove the existing table from the second panel and add the table you want to see (should be in a scroll pane too).  The other is to use something like a card layout and simply switch to the card that corresponds to your radio button.

Comment: Thnx ,I have tried to put the scroll but it was diffuclt,Thnx anyway;) I am going to edit this window and put only buttons in it and make it possible that each button opens a new frame where I can place the table and the SAVE button.thnx

Comment: I can quickly write up some code to do show you, but first do you want the table to be centered in the second panel with extra space surrounding it or do you want it to fill the CENTER of a panel with a BorderLayout?  The difference being the CENTER position of BorderLayout will automatically stretch whatever you put into it to fill all extra space, if you don't want this then I would use a different layout.